# Использование разных экшенов в Ajax.BeginForm в зависимости от условия

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Есть таблица на форме. В неё можно добавлять записи, редактировать или удалять. В зависимости от выбранного действия используются разные экшены контроллера. И если использовать jquery ajax я могу использовтаь например один и тот же ajax запрос передавая в него разные url адреса экшенов и функции успешного и не успешного выполнения. А можно ли при использовании Ajax.BeginForm так же использовать различные экшены в зависимости от ситуации?

Answer (score 0):

да

вот разметка что создается

```
<form action="/Controller/Action" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax- 
   update="#results" id="form0" method="post">    
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Поиск" />
</form>
```

просто менять атрибут action